# анимация между переходами UIViwController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Я делаю простенькое приложение для отображения веб сайтов. На первом вью контроллере я задаю адрес веб страницы, на втором вью я отображаю сайт. Переход осуществляю через сториборды. Мой код:

```
UIStoryboard* storyBoard =  [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
TwoViewController *tvc = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TwoViewController"];

tvc.addres = @"адрес сайта";

[self presentViewController:tvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Все отлично работает. Но в таком случае анимация перехода между контроллерами типа Cover Vertical. Мне бы хотелось получить анимацию типа Flip Horizontal. Как я могу получить такую анимацию через код?

Comment: В UIViewController есть параметер: modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.FlipHorizontal.

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое решение это вместо метода `self.present(yourViewController, animated: Bool, completion: nil)`
использовать `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(yourViewController, animated: Bool)`

Но для этого необходим `UINavigationController`
Если его нет, его можно создать так

`let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: yourViewController)`